# Javascript Blob broken in Chrome 28 extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, blob, multipartform-data, form-data

I have an extension that doesn't work with Chrome 28. I believe there was a security update in regards to passing blobs from one context to another with extensions. I'm trying to verify this and find a workaround if that is the case. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I read in the MDN that if the object's type is not a Blob or File object, it will be converted to a string.... I think this is what is happening. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

**Chrome 28**

The file is properly retrieved and file size is correct. When I check the type, console log, check prototype, etc everything looks correct. The blob size matches the file size. What the server receives if everything takes place in the same window is file data. If it is through the extension, the server receives this string "[object Blob]" and the actual size of the request is the number of bytes for the string "[object Blob]" not the file size.

**Chrome 23**

The file is properly retrieved and file size is correct. When I check the type, console log, check prototype, etc everything looks correct. What the server receives if everything takes place in the same window is file data. If it is through the extension, everything works fine and file data is received. The blob size and the actual file size match when inspected in the console as well as when being sent to the server.

Below is a contrived example. I hope it helps replicate what I am discussing. If not, please let me know and I will upload a working copy to my personal server so you can test it out.

**Extension Tab**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost/someImage.png', true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';

xhr.onload = function (response, status, request) {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (this.response) {
            var blob = new Blob([this.response], { type: 'application/png' });
            blob.name = 'someImage.png';
            window.imageBlob = blob; // For testing
        } else {
            downloadError(response);
        }
    }
};

xhr.onerror = function (e) {
    downloadError(e);
}

xhr.send(null);
```

**Main Tab**

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', imageBlob, imageBlob.name);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost/upload.php', true);

xhr.onload = function (e) {
    console.log('response', xhr.responseText);
}

xhr.send(formData);
```

**Backend**

```
<?php
    print_r($_FILES, true);
?>
```

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to connect these pieces together, and the error you're getting when trying it? "X is broken" is not a very detailed description of the problem.

Comment: I figured the code above was enough to demonstrate the issue, but here is a link to a generic extension making use of the same callback structure I use for the extension. Feel free to try it out. Let me know what you can figure out. http://files.benjaminwalters.net/ChromeExtensionBug.zip

Comment: Your initial code appeared like a very good attempt at explaining what you've tried, but because one section was labeled "Main tab" and the other "Extension tab", I wasn't sure what connected the pieces. I'll check out your zip file.

Comment: It's definitely a bug, possibly related to https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=245296.

Comment: Yeah, i was looking through the chromium repo trying to find a bug and actually ended up reporting it. If there is a resolution from them I'll post it here. Thanks gents!

Comment: Link to bug, for future reference?

Comment: Sorry, been really busy but here's the bug ticket.  https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=265702